# Arabic Text in Crystal Report

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, arabic

I am having issues in displaying Arabic in crystal report. I am pretty sure that the data stored in Oracle is okay because when I query the same data using SQL Developer or TOAD, it is fetching and displaying Arabic contents as well. However, when the same query is used in the Crystal report, it is converting Arabic text into some weird Characters like ãÎÊáÝ etc. However, when I type Arabic in Crystal report, it is fine. The only issue is when I retrieve Arabic data from the database in Crystal report and try to show it, it converts it into some weird characters.

I am using Crystal Report 2008 version 12.0 and I used the font of the field to be "Arial Unicode" but still of no use. I even tried changing the font setting from "right to left"; still no use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use This Font In Crystal Reports `Arabic Typesetting` Its worked With Me and BTW when Print Report with any other Font Will print with correctly Chars That mean Arabic Doesn't work at displaying Only !

Comment: Tried Arabic Typesetting. Its still the same. Regardless of whether I preview the data within Crystal Report, or export it to pdf or see print preview; its the same (when arabic is typed, it is displayed and printed properly, if it has been retrieved from the database, it is converted into some weird characters).

Comment: i am working in Arabic ERP and using Crystal reports  Data in Arabic i get ur problem And when used Arabic Typesetting its over ! 
what is Ur system Default Language ?

Comment: it has been set to Arabic but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use font called (Arial Narrow) it will solve your problem because it use arabic encoding.

right click on the field >> Format object  >> tab Paragraph option Text Interpretation and set it to be RTF Text

Comment: Unfortunately, its still the same. If it is a text object and I type anything in arabic (regardless of the font selected), it is displaying properly; however, when it is a field which is extracted from database and it is in arabic, it gets converted into something weird. I have checked the database using TOAD, it retrieves Arabic text correctly; so no issue with oracle. something must be wrong in the crystal report dataset.

Comment: what version crystal report you are using??

Comment: as mentioned in the question, I am using crystal report 2008 with version 12.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but unfortunately even after changing it to RTF, it is the same. I am suspecting the data-set or something when it is retrieving the arabic data from the database. because if only displaying arabic text was the issue, then how come I am able to use text-boxes with arabic in it.